# レビューを変更することはできますか？

Tags: サポート

間違えて「承認」「却下」してしまった編集に対して、

- 取り消す
- 内容を変更する

といった操作は可能でしょうか？

Answer (score 8, accepted):

レビューしてくれて、ありがとうございます！当サイトの質向上につながります！

現状、間違ったレビューをなおす方法はありません。

複数のレビューアが必要なため、一人がレビューミスをしても大きな問題にならないとは思われますが、気をつけてレビューするのがベストです。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。編集内容だけでなく、何（質問、回答）に対する編集か等しっかり把握してから進めるようにします。